# Ksoap 2 class cast exception in android

Tags: android

I'm developing soap based application.

When i requesting to server I'm getting class cast exception..

My class look like..

```
   package com.example.cafezeeapplication;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.util.Log;

public class SaopCall {

    SaopCall()
    {

    }


    public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/OnlineStatus";

    public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "OnlineStatus"; 

    public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://www.ebidmanagerdemo.com/gjHouseOnline/xml/XMLDataService.asmx";

    InputStream  is;
    String data;

    public String Call()
    {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
    PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();



//  request.addProperty("CafeName", "Cyber Cafe Name");
//  
//  request.addProperty("FromDate", "2012-03-01");
//  
//  request.addProperty("ToDate", "2013-06-03");

    pi.setName("CafeName");
            pi.setValue("Cyber Cafe Name");
            pi.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi);

            pi=new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("FromDate");
            pi.setValue("2012-03-01");
            pi.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi);

            pi=new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("ToDate");
            pi.setValue("2013-06-03");
            pi.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi);



    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    SoapObject response=null;
    try
    {
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();


    //data="count is"+response.getPropertyCount();

    int elementCount ;

    try{
        SoapObject soapObjectGetProperty=(SoapObject) response.getProperty("OnlineStatusResult");

        elementCount = soapObjectGetProperty.getAttributeCount();

        data="count is"+elementCount;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        data=e.toString();
    }


       // data=soapObjectGetProperty.getProperty("MachineIP").toString();


//        
//        Log.i("count", data);
//        if (elementCount > 0) {
//            String element;
//
//            for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
//
//
//              Log.i("Element count",""+ elementCount);
//                element = response.getProperty(i).toString();
//                if(element.equals("MachineIP"))
//                  
//                Log.d("This is an element", Integer.toString(i)
//                        + " --" + element);
//
//
//            }
//        }
//
//  
//  
//  



    //Log.i(response.get," "+ response.getPropertyCount());



        if(data==null)
        {
            data="helllo";
        }


//  
  //data="count:"+response.getPropertyCount()+"  "+response.getPropertyAsString(1);
//  
//  
//  is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    //response=exception.toString();

        exception.printStackTrace();
        data=exception.toString();
    }


    return data;
    }

}
```

Is it my web service respond problem ??
Any problem in my code???

Thanks for all reply...

Comment: try this SoapObject response=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn; instead of this. Also its is better to post the logcat details

Comment: But when i'm using this SoapObject soapObjectGetProperty=(SoapObject) response.getProperty("OnlineStatusResult");        
        elementCount = soapObjectGetProperty.getPropertyCount();

Comment: getting the java.lang.classcast exception:org.ksoap.serialization.soapprimitive